# Tensorflow weights won't change before and after training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to print out the weights of my network before and after training by using this code:

```
weights = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == 'dense1/kernel:0'][0]
print(sess.run(weights))
```

However, the values doesn't change at all.

When I try to debug it by printing out the accuracy along side with the weights, I can see that the accuracy is improving, but the weight remains the same.
The output while training is like:

> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.1551000028848648
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.4083999991416931
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.4812999963760376
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.3167000114917755
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.49880000948905945
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.42320001125335693
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.4494999945163727
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.578000009059906
>
> weights =  [-0.07634658 -0.03764156] acc = 0.6047999858856201

Is it a bug? Or am I printing the weight correctly?

Attached below is a simple model I try to debug

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='3'

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 10]) 

layer1 = tf.layers.dense(X, 2, name='dense1')
output = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 10, name='dense2')

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(y_true, output))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(init)

weights = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == 'dense1/kernel:0'][0]

print("weights before training",sess.run(weights))


for step in range(1000):
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X:batch_x, y_true:batch_y})

    if step % 50 ==0:
        weights = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == 'dense1/kernel:0'][0]
        print("weights = ", sess.run(weights[0]))
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
        acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        print("acc = ",sess.run(acc, feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images, y_true:mnist.test.labels}))




weights_after = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == 'dense1/kernel:0'][0]

print("weights after training",sess.run(weights_after))
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for you to just compare `weights[0]`. You should assign `weights` to `before_weight = sess.run(weights)` before training and  assign `weights` to `after_weight = sess.run(weights)` after training. Then I believe they turn out to be `False` when you compare them with `(before_weight==after_weight).all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights in 'dense1/kernel' (W1) didn't change, but in 'dense2/kernel' (W2) it changed. W2 updated is the reason for the updated accuracy. That means W1 is not being trained by gradient descent, but W2 did. 
Buy the way, add `sess.close()` in the end if you don't use `with tf.Session() as sess:`

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine, but it misses the Model building.
Model(intput=X, output=output)

Comment: The `Model` class is from `Keras`, isn't it? `Tensorflow` should work without using `Keras`.